# Unable to insert clean unicode text back into DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, data-cleaning

I am doing 2 things.
1) filter a dataframe in pandas
2) clean unicode text in a specific column in the filtered dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import probablepeople
from unidecode import unidecode
import re

#read data
df1 = pd.read_csv("H:\\data.csv")
#filter
df1=df1[(df1.gender=="female")]
#reset index because otherwise indexes will be as per original dataframe
df1=df1.reset_index()
```

Now i am trying to clean unicode text in the address column

```
#clean unicode text
for i in range(10):
    df1.loc[i][16] = re.sub(r"[^a-zA-Z.,' ]",r' ',df1.address[i])
```

However, i am unable to do so and below is the error i am getting.

```
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df1=df1[df1.gender=="female"]
#reset index with parameter drop if need new monotonic index (0,1,2,...)
df1=df1.reset_index(drop=True)

df1.address = df1.address.str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z.,' ]",r' ')
```

Comment: Wow! it worked like charm. Care to elaborate on what `str` and `replace` does?

Comment: Ah i see the description link now. Thanks!

Comment: For working with text is best use vectorized function with `str` - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) and `str.replace` works nice with `regex` too.

Comment: I think your solution doesnt work because `loc` is for selecting by column name, not by column position.

Comment: I am new to python and learning about it everyday. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: I am doing this now for 8 million rows and its giving me error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42854573/python-pandas-error-while-removing-extra-white-space/

Comment: Memory error means small memory. Is possible add memory or run python script on server with more memory?