# Python pandas error while removing extra white space

Tags: python, regex, pandas, memory-management, bigdata

I am trying to clean a column in data frame of extra white space using command. The data frame has close to 8 million records

```
datt2.My_variable=datt2.My_variable.str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

I end up getting below error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-158a51cfaa3d> in <module>()
----> 1 datt2.My_variable=datt2.My_variable.str.replace('\s+', ' ')

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags)
   1504     def replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=True, flags=0):
   1505         result = str_replace(self._data, pat, repl, n=n, case=case,
-> 1506                              flags=flags)
   1507         return self._wrap_result(result)
   1508 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags)
    334         f = lambda x: x.replace(pat, repl, n)
    335 
--> 336     return _na_map(f, arr)
    337 
    338 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in _na_map(f, arr, na_result, dtype)
    152 def _na_map(f, arr, na_result=np.nan, dtype=object):
    153     # should really _check_ for NA
--> 154     return _map(f, arr, na_mask=True, na_value=na_result, dtype=dtype)
    155 
    156 

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.pyc in _map(f, arr, na_mask, na_value, dtype)
    167         try:
    168             convert = not all(mask)
--> 169             result = lib.map_infer_mask(arr, f, mask.view(np.uint8), convert)
    170         except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    171 

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer_mask (pandas\lib.c:65837)()

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.maybe_convert_objects (pandas\lib.c:56806)()

MemoryError:
```

Comment: What if you use `datt2.My_variable.str.replace(r'\s+', ' ', inplace=True, regex=True)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, there is no parameter 'inplace' or 'regex' in this function. I still went ahead and executed it and error message this time as expected was `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'`

Comment: Is this a lot of data you are dealing with?

Comment: Yes, couple of million records

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I am trying to clean **a column** in data frame of extra white space ...
>       `datt2.My_variable=datt2.My_variable.str.replace('\s+', ' ')`

Please comment, do I understand your `expression` correctly?

```
 pandas       Column           Column              DataSeries
 DataFrame     Name           DataSeries             Methode
|-^-|       |----^-----|   |-------^-------|  |----------^----------|
datt2       .My_variable = datt2.My_variable  .str.replace('\s+', ' ')
```

---

I'm pretty sure using `re.sub` is the same as use `pandas.str.replace(...)`, but without copy the whole `column` Data.

> **From the `pandas` doc:**
>    Series.str.replace(pat, repl, n=-1, case=True, flags=0)
>       Replace occurrences of pattern/regex in the Series/Index with some other string.
>       Equivalent to str.replace() or re.sub().

---

Try pure `python`, for instance:

```
    import re
    for idx in df.index:
        df.loc[idx, 'My_variable'] = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ', df.loc[idx, 'My_variable'])
```

**Note**: Consider to use **'\s\s+'** instead of '\s+'.
Using '\s+' will replace **ONE BLANK** with **ONE BLANK**, which is useless.

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - pandas:0.19.2***
Come back and Flag your Question as answered if this is working for you or comment why not.

Comment: This is a loop, isn't it? That is precisely the reason why I went with vectorized form of regex substitution for entire dataframe column. This does not answer my original question.

Comment: In a pandas dataframe, we have rows and columns. In re.sub, for a pandas column, you have to process everything row by row through a loop just like the code chunk you have posted. However, pandas.str.replace can process the entire column without having to write a loop. This has worked for me in the past. However the data i am using wight now is 8 million rows. This library is unable to scale for this amount of data.

Comment: @Enthusiast: I see your point, please verify, do I understand your `expression` correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'expression'? i only want to clean all cells of the column at once. that's it.

Comment: @Enthusiast: I have updated my Answer to show what I mean with `expression`.